# How do I select customers where their first three orders match certain values?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have a table shop_orders, and I want to look up all of the customer_id where their first 3 order_type are "Book", "Coffee" and "Pen" in that order.

Source table would look like this:

```
customer_id  order_type  order_time
6872         Coffee      2018-04-06 15:06
6455         Book        2018-04-06 15:08
6872         Coffee      2018-04-06 19:12
6455         Coffee      2018-04-07 15:08
5217         Pen         2018-04-08 09:11
5217         Book        2018-04-08 10:55
6455         Pen         2018-04-09 05:22
6455         Coffee      2018-04-09 07:46
```

As user 6455's first three orders are "Book", "Coffee", and "Pen", the query should return:

```
customer_id
6455
```

I am using BigQuery for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT customer_id
FROM `project.dataset.shop_orders`
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING STRING_AGG(order_type ORDER BY order_time LIMIT 3) = 'Book,Coffee,Pen'
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.shop_orders` AS (
  SELECT 6872 customer_id, 'Coffee' order_type, '2018-04-06 15:06' order_time UNION ALL
  SELECT 6455, 'Book', '2018-04-06 15:08' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6872, 'Coffee', '2018-04-06 19:12' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6455, 'Coffee', '2018-04-07 15:08' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5217, 'Pen', '2018-04-08 09:11' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5217, 'Book', '2018-04-08 10:55' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6455, 'Pen', '2018-04-09 05:22' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6455, 'Coffee', '2018-04-09 07:46'
)
SELECT customer_id
FROM `project.dataset.shop_orders`
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING STRING_AGG(order_type ORDER BY order_time LIMIT 3) = 'Book,Coffee,Pen'
```

with result

```
Row customer_id  
1   6455
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but the string_agg function that BigQuery accepted looked like this: STRING_AGG(order_type, "," ORDER BY order_time LIMIT 3)

Comment: Delimiter is optional!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .

```
select customer_id
from t
group by customer_id
having array_to_string(array_agg(order_type order by order_time limit 3), ',') = 'Book,Coffee,Pen';
```

Here is the code:

```
with t as (
      select 6872 as customer_id, 'Coffee' as order_type, '2018-04-06 15:06' as order_time union all
      select 6455, 'Book', '2018-04-06 15:08' union all
      select 6872, 'Coffee', '2018-04-06 19:12' union all
      select 6455, 'Coffee', '2018-04-07 15:08' union all
      select 5217, 'Pen', '2018-04-08 09:11' union all
      select 5217, 'Book', '2018-04-08 10:55' union all
      select 6455, 'Pen', '2018-04-09 05:22' union all
      select 6455, 'Coffee', '2018-04-09 07:46'
     )
select customer_id, array_to_string(array_agg(order_type order by order_time limit 3), ',')
from t
group by customer_id
having array_to_string(array_agg(order_type order by order_time limit 3), ',') = 'Book,Coffee,Pen';
```

Comment: This was more or less what I used, but BigQuery wouldn't accept array_agg or array_to_string so I used  STRING_AGG(order_type, "," ORDER BY order_time LIMIT 3)

Comment: @Thissiteusescookies . . . I ran the code it BigQuery.  It works.  Are you sure you are using Standard SQL?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below by using `exists` and `row_number()`

```
  with cte as
 (
  select *,row_number()over(partition by customer_id order by order_time ) rn
  from table    
 ), cte1 as
 (
  select * from cte where rn<=3
 ) select * from cte1 t1
   where exists( select 1 from cte1 t2 where t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id
                and t2.rn=1 and t2.order_type='Book'
                )
              and exists ( select 1 from cte1 t2
              where t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id
                and t2.rn=2 and t2.order_type='Coffee'
                )
               and exists ( select 1 from cte1 t2
              where t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id
                and t2.rn=3 and t2.order_type='Pen'

            )
```

output

```
customer_id     order_type  order_time  rn
6455    Book    2018-04-06 15:08        1
6455    Coffee  2018-04-07 15:08        2
6455    Pen     2018-04-09 05:22        3
```

[demo in sql server but will work bigquery also](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0da19466dea727579850240ba81d00e6)